# How to get data from different tables in MySQL database and display in a table with php

Tags: php, mysql

I have read many topics but none have given me exactly what i need

I have 3 tables

**products**

| id | product_name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Heineken |
| 2 | Budweiser |

**transaction**

| id | user_id | date | amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 32 | 4 | 01/23/2023 | 10000 |
| 45 | 2 | 01/23/2023 | 20000 |
| 57 | 4 | 01/23/2023 | 5000 |

**transaction_details**

| id | transaction_id | product_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 32 | 1 |
| 2 | 32 | 2 |
| 3 | 45 | 2 |
| 4 | 45 | 1 |
| 5 | 57 | 1 |

Now how can i achieve this

SELECT FROM **transaction** WHERE user_*id = 4   then use the results to SELECT FROM* **transaction_details** and display it in a table using a single sql query

And when displaying the results from **transaction_details**  i want to use product_name

This is the result i want

| transaction_id | products_id and name |
| --- | --- |
| 32 | 1. Heineken |
| 32 | 2. Budweiser |
| 57 | 1. Heineken |

I have tried to select from transaction table where id is equal to 4 and i got two results, i don't know what to do next

Comment: use `join` query

Comment: Please add the code you have tried to your question. As suggested below, you should join between your three tables (instead of nesting queries in loops) but you should avoid the CONCAT (for this use case) and keep that for your display logic in PHP. `SELECT * FROM transaction tx JOIN transaction_details txd ON tx.id = txd.transaction_id JOIN products p ON txd.product_id = p.id WHERE tx.user_id = 4`. [Have a play with this](https://dbfiddle.uk/eaFcN9kb).

Answer (score 0):

Using Mysqli Join Query with select concat option in in your select query

Please Using This Way

```
select tran.id,CONCAT(pro.id,'.',pro.product_name) as products_id_and_name from transaction as tran join transaction_details as trand on tran.id = trand.transaction_id JOIN products as pro on pro.id = trand.product_id WHERE tran.user_id = 4;
```